# when i type command at windows terminal http-server

Tags: ide, blockchain, provider, remix

when i type command at windows terminal **http-server** following error occured

```
error
 http-server
http-server : File C:\Users\RKanth\AppData\Roaming\npm\http-server.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see    about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ http-server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open PowerShell by Run as Administrator
2. Run the following command:

   `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine`
3. Confirm with ‘Y’

Answer (score 0):

1. Open PowerShell by Running as Administrator using the windows search bar.
2. Run the following command: `Get-ExecutionPolicy`
3. Then you can See: `Restricted`
4. Again run the following command: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestrict`
5. Press ***y***
6. Now you can Run again the following command and check: `Get-ExecutionPolicy`
7. Then you can See: `Unrestricted`
8. Done!!!